# Authentication in Microservices with API Gateway

Tags: microservices

I have a simple question; I'm building a microservices project, with an API Gateway in front of my services.
Actually , all my ms ( microservices ) have an internal domain: http://ms.mydomain.lan
MS are behind an Api Gateway, that handle authentication.
All ms API are not accessible to the external.

So, all the traffic pass throught the Api Gateway: https://api.mydomain.it.

This is the core of the problem.

During the auth in Api Gateway, I detect the user and create a TOKEN ( not really a jwt, a simple encoded string )

This token is sent to ms requests using headers. Each MS decode the token ( that is NOT A JWT ), get the user and handle permission etc etc...

All work well BUT ... my doubt is: should each microservice perform a "token validation" , or it is not necessary?

Actually, a microservice decode a simple string; I'm sure that ms are NOT accessible to the outside, so no one can create a fake token.

But ... is the right way to do this? I'm thinking to create a JWT so that each MS has to validate the token with an authService but ... why should I add this overhead? is really necessary? I have to add an extra call to a service that has to validate the token ... Or I could store jwt secret in an NFS location and let the ms to validate the token by himself ...

Which is the best way to proceed? Is the validation of token really necessary in each single microservice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should have been answered somewhere ! Ideally each MS should validate the JWT token , validation can happen using the TTL parameter too, when the token is generated , generator (or server) can set that value

Comment: This seems to be nice implementation. Only concern point and that needs to keep in mind in all future development that you MicroService will never access externally. It must access through API Gateway. If implementation stick to this then it is good.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are using is good. The api gateway handles the authentication and transfers the request to the internal services. The ms trust the gateway and perform only the authorization.

Wether you use a JWT token for internal communication is up to you. A simple string should suffice if the ms can use it for authorization.

I use the same pattern when building microservices.